# Webpack 4 not generating the webpackBootstrap function when more than 2 reducers

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, webpack-4

I have an application that i have upgraded to the latest versions of Webpack, React and Redux.  Webpack is not generating the webpackBootstrap function when more that two reducers are added to redux using combineReducers.  I suspect this may be a bug in Webpack but I am uncertain.  I have spent several weeks/hours chasing down this issue without success.  Also this code worked with an older version of webpack.  I have tried to outline the problem so it can be recreated with out putting all the code here.  Any ideas.

update: after updating to the latest version on webpack (4.16.5) the source code will not generate the webpackBootstrap under any conditions.

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/stuartsimpson/webpackbug)

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "webpack4react",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node bin/www",
        "build": "webpack --mode development --watch --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^1.3.1",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
        "debug": "~2.6.3",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "history": "^4.7.2",
        "jade": "~1.11.0",
        "less-middleware": "^3.0.1",
        "morgan": "^1.9.0",
        "react": "^16.4.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "redux": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-promise-middleware": "^5.1.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
        "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "webpack": "^4.14.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
    }
}
```

I have three Reducers that I am trying to add to my redux Store using combinneReducers.  If I only add two reducers webpack generates the the webpackBootstrap function however if i add a third reducer webpack stops generating the webpackBootstrap function and pushes the code onto webpackJsonp stack.

I have created a very simple application that creates two bundles. one bundle is the nodeModules (React, Redux so on). The other bundle is my application code.

**webpack.conif.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const env = {
    mode:'development',
    devtool:'false',
    entry:{
        core: './public/javascripts/core/index.js',
        nodeModules:[
            'react',
            'react-dom',
            '@material-ui/core'
        ]
    },
    output:{
        filename:'[name]/bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/dist/')
    },
    module:{
        rules:[{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use:{
                loader:'babel-loader'
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins:[
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/indexTemplate.html'
        }),
        new visualizer({filename:'./webpackStats.html'})
    ],
    optimization:{
        splitChunks:{
            chunks:"all",
            cacheGroups:{
                nodeModules:{
                    name:"nodeModules",
                    test:/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
                },
                core:{
                    name:"core",
                    test:/[\\/]core[\\/]/
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
```

module.exports = env;

My three reducers are very simple:

**feedbackReducer.js**

```
import stateStorage from '../../util/stateStorage';

var feedbackReducer = (state = stateStorage.get('footerState', {message: '',}), action) => {
    let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FEEDBACK_POST_MESSAGE': {
            newState.message = action.payload;
            break;
        }
    }
    return(newState);
};

export default feedbackReducer;
```

**menuReducer.js**

```
import stateStorage from '../../util/stateStorage';

var menuReducer = (state = stateStorage.get('menuState', {menu: {}, drawerOpen: false, drawerDocked: false}), action) => {
    let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_MENU_STATE':{
            newState.menu = action.payload.menu;
            state = newState;
            break;
        }
        case 'OPEN_MENU_DRAWER':{
            newState.drawerOpen = true;
            break;
        }
        case 'CLOSE_MENU_DRAWER':{
            newState.drawerOpen = false;
            break;
        }
        case 'DOCK_MENU_DRAWER':{
            newState.drawerDocked = true;
            break;
        }
        case 'UNDOCK_MENU_DRAWER':{
            newState.drawerDocked = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return(newState);
};

export default menuReducer;
```

**newReducer.js**

```
import stateStorage from '../../util/stateStorage';

var newReducer = (state = stateStorage.get('newReducerState', {message: '',}), action) => {
    let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FEEDBACK_POST_MESSAGE': {
            newState.message = action.payload;
            break;
        }
    }
    return(newState);
};

export default newReducer;
```

you will notice the feedbackReducer and newReducer are identical functions other than in name.

If I use the following code for my coreReducers function:

```
import feedbackReducer from './feedbackReducer';
import menuReducer from './menuReducer';
import newReducer from './newReducer';

function coreReducers(){
    var reducerList = {
        menuState: menuReducer,
        newReducer: newReducer
    };
    return(reducerList);
}

export default coreReducers;
```

webpack generates the webpackBootrap function correctly.  However if I modify the coreReducers function to:

```
import feedbackReducer from './feedbackReducer';
import menuReducer from './menuReducer';
import newReducer from './newReducer';

function coreReducers(){
    var reducerList = {
        footerState: feedbackReducer,
        menuState: menuReducer,
        newReducer: newReducer
    };
    return(reducerList);
}

export default coreReducers;
```

Webpack stops generating

```
(function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
```

and starts generating

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["core"],{
```

Comment: @Joel the problem with  your edit is it does not represent the name of the function as it appears in the generated code.  webpack will generate an anonymous function and then comments it as being webpackBootstrap.  your edit may confuse it with the product know as Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted to the Webpack group and was told the splitChunks section was in correct and that it should be removed.  Unfortuntaly this miss configuration was giving me inconsistant output when on webpack 4.14 and then after upgrading to 4.16.5 webpack constantly generated the bundle without the webpackBootstrap function.  After removing the splitChunks section webpack began to generate the bundle with the webpackBootstrap function as expected. I will continue to do additional research on understanding how splitChunks works.